# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging HIPAA Compliant?

Tags: firebase

I want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging in a healthcare application. I want to know is FCM HIPAA Compliant and does it provide BAA?

Comment: Wondering if anyone has any updates on this topic.

Answer (score 14):

We’ve just completed the HIPAA audit with a 3rd party for a Firestore Chat sample app (iOS and Android) that’s using End-to-End Encryption. If you’re implementing a healthcare Chat app, keep reading. Otherwise, this isn’t relevant.

The challenge: if you know how E2EE works, you realize that it alone should protect your patients’ data from Firebase/Firestore: apparently, lawyers don’t agree with that. So we had to implement an artificial data redaction that deletes chat messages from Firestore as soon as the messages are delivered. This enables your app to qualify for HIPAA’s Conduit exception, because it only acts as a message delivery system, it doesn’t store permanent health data. This way, your chat solution is exempt of HIPAA.

We’ve compiled the solution into a How-to blog post: https://VirgilSecurity.com/hipaa-firebase - with pointers to reusable sample apps.

Whitepaper that contains our HIPAA audit & 3rd-party data privacy expert’s notes: https://VirgilSecurity.com/firebase-whitepaper

Comment: Thanks for the information. I also interested to know "how E2EE works?" If you can point me to some resource that will be great.

Comment: Briefly: 

1. Each user will have a unique private key (generated on the user device at signup-time or next login-time; the key will never leave the device for security reasons).

2. The respective user public key is published in the cloud for each user to be able to look up each other's public keys.

3. When Alice sends a msg to Bob, she downloads Bob's and her own public keys and uses them to encrypt the msg.

4. Then, your app will send over the encrypted message via Firestore/any DB to Bob.

5. Bob receives the encrypted msg and uses his own private key to decrypt it.

Comment: As of recently Cloud Firestore is covered by Google's BAA https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/

Comment: @DavidSzabo, i saw that your app is using the firebase auth, which is not HIPAA compliant, to perform the login. how did you address this issue?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/eckvou1Oz8o

Answer (score 3):

According to the co-founder, as of now Firebase is not HIPAA compliant.

You can take a look at the updates here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sg-WCHVXs5k