# How can I achieve HIPAA compliance using cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have to work on a health app and was wondering if I can use Cloud Firestore as a backend for it. 
Can any one comment on How can I get my system HIPAA Compliant? 
Are there any third party/open source libraries that I can use for it.

Comment: FYI, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/8Qr4HypzE3E and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151630/is-firebase-cloud-messaging-hipaa-compliant

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a coding question, and is better (and already) addressed on the firebase-talk mailing list.

Comment: Short answer is legally it's not a great idea, because Google won't enter into a BAA for the firestore service. See their covered products here: https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/

You can still store information not regulated by hipaa in firestore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the question can you have a look?

Comment: For posterity: Cloud Firestore is now covered by the standard Google Cloud BAA. https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa

Comment: @ColinMcDonnell Hi, just wondering if you know firebase is also covered by hipaa?